# JavaScript, No JQuery Please, how to get total count of specific tag inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to get the total count of a specific tag inside an iframe on the same domain. I am currently using this working example without iframe:

```
<div id="id_of_first_div">
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
    <div>
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
var top_level_div = document.getElementById('id_of_first_div');
var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('p').length;
document.write(count);
</script>
```

Comment: and what is wrong with your solution?

Comment: You can't access the contents of an iframe. Otherwise you could point it to `http://common-bank.com/` and read all the data of the user.

Comment: You are wrong @Waleed, you can't access it only if its on another domain.

Comment: Did you try to do it with an iframe?

Comment: it'll be on the same domain

Comment: Do not use document.write for debugging. Use the console. You also have to make sure the iframe is actually loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the iframe is on the same domain as the containing window:

```
ifr = // your preferred method of getting the <iframe> element, getElementById preferred
count = ifr.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('p').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same domain :

```
function getFrameCount(iframeID, elem){
   var iFrame = document.getElementById(iframeID), iFrame_p;
   if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) { // FF etc.
     iFrame_p = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName(elem);
   } else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) { // IE
     iFrame_p = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
   }
   return iFrame_p.lenght;
}

var number_of_p = getFrameCount('iframeID', 'p');
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to create nice code is to create method for getting iframe content, cause its different for some browsers.

```
function getIframeContent(frmName)
{
  var iframe = document.getElementById(frmName);
  var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument :   iframe.contentWindow.document;
  return innerDoc;
}
```

and then access elements like `getIframeContent.getElementsByTagName....`
I hope that this helps you.